# Loading a js file valid throughout project Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So, currently I am working on a project in Reactjs that displays a customised modal.
The configuration of the modal is fetched through a `configurationLoader.js` file.

Since, it is developed in React, my components are divided across different files. 
Currently, what I am doing is, loading the full configuration file and extracting the relevant information when required.

What I find redundant is, I have to `require` the configuration file at the start of every `.js` file.

Is there a way, where I export my module once, and its valid globally? .i.e. I don't have to require it again and again?

Comment: Explicit dependencies at the head of a file are common across many languages, and are considered a feature by them that aids in debugging.  Consider C# 'using' or Java 'import' statements.

Answer (score 1):

Globals are registered in the `window` object for the browser and in the `global` object in node. So you could do:

`window.myConfiguration = require('configurationLoader')`

or

`global.myConfiguration = require('configurationLoader')`

depending on where your code will run. Then you should be able to access `myConfiguration` anywhere in your code without needing to require it.